# Convert C++ program into assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and suppose I have to write some program. Can I make it such that Visual Studio shows me this code translated into assembly language?

And if yes how do I do it? For example, I have a factorial program:

```
int fact(int n) {
    if (n<=1)  
        return 1;
    return n*fact(n-1);
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-msvc-if-relevent) question:

> There are several approaches:
>
> 1. You can normally see assembly code while debugging C++ in visual
>      studio (and eclipse too). For this in
>      Visual Studio put a breakpoint on code
>      in question and when debugger hits it
>      rigth click and find "Go To Assembly"
>      ( or press CTRL+ALT+D )
> 2. Second approach is to generate assembly listings while compiling. For
>      this go to project settings -> C/C++
>      -> Output Files -> ASM List Location and fill in file name. Also select
>      "Assembly Output" to "Assembly With
>      Source Code".
> 3. Compile the program and use any third-party debugger. You can use
>      OllyDbg or WinDbg for this. Also you
>      can use IDA (interactive
>      disassembler). But this is hardcore
>      way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Put a breakpoint into your factorial function, start debugging, go to Call Stack window, right click on your function, select Go To Disassembly

Comment: Although this answer is technically correct I'd say it's an inch off the expectation.