# return type before or after __declspec?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, declaration

should I use

```
bool __declspec(dllexport) function()
{ 
    return true;
}
```

or

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool function()
{
    return true;
}
```

what is the difference between these two?
Will this affect how the functions are executed or what they return when called from an application? (this code is ment for a DLL).

Comment: Did you check the assembly?

Comment: how to do that in VS2012? :P

Comment: This answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-msvc-if-relevent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are accepted by the compiler, it's hard to see how they can be anything other than exactly equivalent.

Comment: and what about the C++ "standard"?

Comment: @GamErix: This is a Microsoft extension and has nothing to do with the C++ standard.

Comment: @GamErix: How can the standard talk about compiler-specific extensions?

Comment: even if it's a extension which can be coded both ways, there is no specification on what should be used?

Comment: @GamErix: Have a look at MSDN. There's probably a grammar somewhere on there. I couldn't find it. All the examples I've seen use the second form.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP case shown it doesn't matter, although there is a recommended form.

From **`__declspec` Grammar** on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/declspec?view=msvc-170):

> The `__declspec` keywords should be placed at the beginning of a
> simple declaration. The compiler ignores, without warning, any
> `__declspec` keywords placed after * or & and in front of the variable
> identifier in a declaration.
> [...]
> The general guideline for using the `__declspec` attribute for simple
> declarations is as follows:
> [...]
>
> ```
> __declspec(selectany) int * pi1 = 0;  //Recommended, selectany & int both part of decl-specifier
> int __declspec(selectany) * pi2 = 0;  //OK, selectany & int both part of decl-specifier
> int * __declspec(selectany) pi3 = 0;  //ERROR, selectany is not part of a declarator
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One of the cases that I have seen it can make a difference is when the function returns a pointer:

The following leads to `error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(dllexport)'`:

```
int* __declspec(dllexport) func_1();
double* __declspec(dllexport) func_2();
```

The following compiles successfully:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int* func_1();
__declspec(dllexport) double* func_2();
```

So, one may decide to keep `__declspec(dllexport)` consistently before the function return type.