# Is Visual Studio emitting erroneous assembly code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86

Disassembling the following function using VS2010

```
int __stdcall modulo(int a, int b)
{
    return a % b;
}
```

gives you:

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
cdq  
idiv        eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
mov         eax,edx  
pop         ebp  
ret         8
```

which is pretty straightforward.

Now, trying the same assembly code as inline assembly fails with `error C2414: illegal number of operands`, pointing to idiv.

I read [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and it says that idiv accept only 1 operand:

> Divides the (signed) value in the AX, DX:AX, or EDX:EAX (dividend) by
>   the source operand (divisor) and stores the  result in the AX (AH:AL),
>   DX:AX, or EDX:EAX registers

and sure enough, removing the extra eax compiles and the function returns the correct result.

So, what is going on here? why is VS2010 emitting erroneous code ? (btw, VS2012 emits exactly the same assembly)

Comment: Did you generate assembly output (by the compiler) or did you disassemble a compiled binary?

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: @FredLarson I assume he's using the assembler that comes with VS 2010 (ml.exe).

Comment: I am using the disassembly feature from within the IDE

Comment: @xxbbcc: You can assume that, but it may not be the case. If the generated assembly code is from VS2010, I would expect its assembler to be able to handle the format.

Comment: @Yuval See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c and generate assembly out when you compile.

Comment: @FredLarson you would hope so, but you will often be disappointed.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Yes, especially since it's copied out of the IDE disassembly window as opposed to being a generated .asm file. That could be a whole different ball game.

Comment: @xxbbcc I followed your suggestion and indeed, the idiv statement was correctly emitted. Now the question is, why is there any difference?

Comment: @Yuval I'm not sure. It could be a bug or it could be intentional. I personally never expected the disassembly output to be correct assembly (can't explain why). You should post this as a bug to Microsoft and see what response you get. (My bet is "Won't fix".)

Comment: @Yuval As a general rule, I'd never fully trust anything decompiled, that's why I suggested to use the compiler's assembly output.

Comment: @xxbbcc did you mean decompiled or disassembled? Any way, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Yuval I meant decompiled and / or disassembled code. When it comes to syntax, only the compiler's output is reliable (and even that could be buggy, just not very likely).

Answer (score 1):

The difference, most likely, is that the author of the disassembler intended for its output to be read by a human rather than by an assembler. Since it's a disassembly, one assumes the underlying code has already been assembled/compiled, so why worry about whether it can be re-assembled?

There are two major possibilities here:

- The author didn't realize or didn't remember that the dividend is implicit for `idiv` (in which case this could be considered a bug).
- They felt that making it explicit in the output would be helpful for a reader trying to understand the flow of the disassembly (in which case it's a feature). Without the explicit operand, it would be easy to overlook that `idiv` both depends on and modifies `eax` when scanning the disassembly.