# clang interleaved source and assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, assembly, clang

Wondering if it is possible to generate interleaved source and assembly from clang?
I am looking for something equivalent to gcc command (as demonstrated at http://www.fclose.com/240/generate-a-mixed-source-and-assembly-listing-using-gcc/)

```
gcc -Wa,-adhln -g source_code.c > assembly_list.s
```

I have visited Link: [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137038/how-do-you-get-assembler-output-from-c-c-source-in-gcc) but it gets so far as to list the assembly - but no interleaving.

Also Visual Studio does give you pretty nice interleaved assembly output, details here: [How to view the assembly behind the code using Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c)

Thank you for all the help.

Sarang

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a bug reported sometimes last year stating exactly this: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16647

```
Bug 16647 - No option to produce mixed source + assembly listing?
```

So since it is still `NEW` I guess clang does not have this supported yet.

As an alternative, how about compiling your code and then use `objdump -S` ? The output format is somewhat similar ...

Answer (score 6):

As of August 2016, the bug that @dragosht mentioned still is open. However, there is a workaround offered by [the linked bug 17465](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17465): `clang -no-integrated-as -Xassembler -adhln`. It disables the clang-integrated assembler and calls an external assembler, which hopefully supports the listing-generating options.

That works OK in Linux, but it doesn't work in Mac OS X (as of 10.11.6). The problem is that even the external assembler in OS X does not support the listing-generating options - you can check that with `man as`.

`objdump -S` is an alternative that also works well in Linux, but Mac OS X's alternative to objdump is otool, which does provide disassembly but not source interlacing. Hopefully that will change soon-ish, because otool seems to be on its way out while llvm grows its own objdump. See `man llvm-otool`.

Finally, for OS X the best option seems to be using `gobjdump -S`, from binutils. It can be installed with MacPorts or brew.

Answer (score 0):

You can Generate Assembly Code from a .cc/.cpp source file by using this command

```
clang++ -c -S test-function.cc
```

Comment: And then assembling it with `as -adhln test-function.s` works to make a listing that mixes C++ lines with asm lines?  That's the point of this question, not just getting asm by itself.