# Generate list file to compare source file with assembly file in clang compiler

Tags: gcc, clang

As mentioned in this link
http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html

> *How can I create a file where I can see the C code and its assembly translation together?*
>
> **Res:** If you want to see the C code together with the assembly it was converted to, use a command line like this:
>
> ```
>     gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad [other GCC options] foo.c > foo.lst
> ```

I tried to make the same thing in the Mac OSX Yosemite terminal and received the following errors:

```
    $ gcc -Wa,-a,-ad main.c > main.lst

    clang: error: unsupported argument '-a' to option 'Wa,'  
    clang: error: unsupported argument '-ad' to option 'Wa,'
```

So, I'm looking for a way to generate a file with the assembly +source approach in the clang compiler, if there's one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `gcc ` is just a link to clang. Maybe you want to install GCC (from Homebrew or MacPorts)?

Comment: For solve the problem I made that, but I still want to know the clang compiler approach, specially for the general case with C++ and Objective C source files

Comment: possible duplicate of [clang interleaved source and assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603910/clang-interleaved-source-and-assembly)