# Is it possible to embed LLVM IR directly into C++ source when using clang?

Tags: clang

In Clang, is there a way to embed LLVM IR directly into C++?  For example, can a GNU-style `asm` statement contain LLVM IR instead of machine code?

More specifically, I'm adding some experimental intrinsics to LLVM, and would like to generate calls to them from C++.  Do I have to modify Clang to do this, or is there a shortcut?

Comment: Not yet- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603910/clang-interleaved-source-and-assembly

Comment: Thanks. I'll add a `__builtin_` function that expands to my intrinsic.