# C++, Visual Studio Disassembly Not Availble

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, disassembly

I'm trying to view the disassembly of my code as explained in the article below:

[How to view the assembly behind the code using Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c)

But I can't seem to find the disassmebly option:
[image]

Any help on this issue would be most appreciated.

Additional Notes: It is a win32 debug project in C++.

Comment: are you debugging your code?

Comment: yep, its in debug mode. A win32 debug project.

Comment: Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly

Comment: @rpress its not there either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MS Visual Studio 2012 and I see option "Go to disassembly" when debugging code. I suppose that such features can depend on Visual Studio edition. So see your version and refer to http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx

Also, maybe some options of IDE switch this option, see http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/PTX_SASS_Assembly_Debugging.htm

Comment: ah, brilliant thanks :). It was the second one. I'm using VS Ultimate.