# why does C++, DevStudio, array indices work?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

WCHAR *HiveName[4] = {L"HKCR", L"HKCU", L"HKLM", L"HKU"};

int wmain( INT argc, WCHAR **argv )
{
    for ( DWORD i = 0x80000000; i < 0x80000004; i++ )
        wprintf(L"%lu %s\n", i, HiveName[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 2147483648 HKCR
>
> 2147483649 HKCU
>
> 2147483650 HKLM
>
> 2147483651 HKU

Why does it work?

Comment: You're going out of bounds of the array, that leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which really makes all speculation about behavior useless.

Comment: Are you compiling as x86 or x64?

Comment: Also, if you really want to know what is happening here, it's useful to look at the [assembly listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c).

Comment: x86 ... I read that static arrays are limited in size to 0x7FFFFFFF.  So wrapping indices there makes some sense.

Comment: From the ASM ... It's multiplying the index by 4 (size of DWORD) to get bytes I imagine. Wrapped at 2^32, that gives 0, 1, 2, 3.  It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Some Programmer Dude says, out of bounds array indexing is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means that according to the ISO C++ standard, the compiler is allowed to emit anything at all.  The compiler could even emit a virus that encrypts your hard drive, and it would still be a standards compliant compiler.

That having been said, I have some speculation about what may be happening.

On Windows, x86 user space processes can use [virtual addresses from `0x00000000` to `0x7fffffff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366912(v=vs.85).aspx).  `0x80000000` and above is reserved for the kernel by default, although there are ways to increase this as high as 3 GB.  In any case, it seems the limit on any particular allocation is 2 GB, so there's absolutely no way that an index of `0x80000000` or higher could point to a validly allocated object.  The compiler is then free to emit code on the assumption that `i` must somehow be less than `0x80000000`.

In this case there may not be any real "optimization."  One version of the MSVC compiler outputs [the following](https://godbolt.org/g/XQinX8) for the array indexing operation:

```
push    DWORD PTR wchar_t ** HiveName[esi*4]
```

Here, `esi` contains the index, `i`.  It gets multiplied by 4, which is `sizeof(wchar_t*)`, the array element.  This overflows, and it happens to always give the right answer because the most significant bit always gets thrown out.

Comment: Thanks, Jack C.!  Of course, it multiplies by 4 to get to the next pointer, not to the next DWORD as I said in an earlier comment.  So it was indefined behavior together with a bit of luck.  I was doing arithmetic on the actual values of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (0x80000000) and friends ... discovered my own mistake but then wondered why it worked anyway.