# How to compare number instructions of two algorithm in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++14, signal-processing

I have a need to compare the performance of two algorithmic approaches to do the same DSP function in written in C++ using VS2017

Each algorithm takes the same signal data and processes it into the same output over the same period of time - it is sample frequency-based so in this instance 48KHz.

I really want to know the count of instructions - or some valid proxy - by which I can compare them to draw a conclusion as to which is more efficient.

Comment: You may [look at the compiled code's assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c) and count the number of instructions. That's one metric you could try to relate to performance, but beware that not all instructions have the same execution time and latency, and other factors such as caching may also greatly affect performance.

Comment: Yes, thank you @SleuthEye that is the approach we've taken. It just seems a little cumbersome in the 21st century.